# What type of action is healing hymn?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

What type of action does activating healing hymn consume? It is a spell-like ability, but  it does not emulate a spell and it doesn't specify in its text what kind of action it uses, so I'm not certain.

**Healing Hymn (Complete Champion 47)**:

> If you have 3 or more ranks in a Perform skill, you can use your music
>   or poetics to create an area conducive to healing.
>
> To be affected, an ally must be able to see and hear you perform. The effect lasts as long as you continue performing and
>   for 5 rounds thereafter. An affected ally who casts any conjuration
>   (healing) spell gains a +1 sacred (if you’re good or neutral) or
>   profane (if you’re evil) bonus on the roll for each rank you have in
>   the Perform skill. This ability has no effect on spells cast from
>   wands, scrolls, or other magic items.
>
> In addition, if you use this ability for 1 full minute before you and your allies retire for the night, everyone in
>   the group heals naturally as if he had completed 24 hours of bed rest
>   (thus recovering twice his character level in hit points). If the
>   music is interrupted, the magic of the song is lost.
>
> Either use of healing hymn counts as one daily use of your bardic
>   music ability.

**Spell Like Abilities:**

> [Spell-Like Abilities](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm) (Sp) Usually, a spell-like ability works
>   just like the spell of that name. A few spell-like abilities are
>   unique; these are explained in the text where they are described.
>
> A spell-like ability has no verbal, somatic, or material component,
>   nor does it require a focus or have an XP cost. The user activates it
>   mentally. Armor never affects a spell-like ability’s use, even if the
>   ability resembles an arcane spell with a somatic component.
>
> A spell-like ability takes the same amount of time to complete as the
>   spell that it mimics (usually 1 standard action) unless otherwise
>   stated. Spell-like abilities cannot be used to counterspell, nor can
>   they be counterspelled. In all other ways, a spell-like ability
>   functions just like a spell:
>
> Using a spell-like ability while threatened provokes attacks of
>   opportunity. It is possible to make a Concentration check to use a
>   spell-like ability defensively and avoid provoking an attack of
>   opportunity. A spell-like ability can be disrupted just as a spell can
>   be. Spell-like abilities are subject to spell resistance and to being
>   dispelled by dispel magic. They do not function in areas where magic
>   is suppressed or negated.
>
> A spell-like ability usually has a limit on how often it can be used.
>   A spell-like ability that can be used at will has no use limit.
>
> For creatures with spell-like abilities, a designated caster level
>   defines how difficult it is to dispel their spell-like effects and to
>   define any level-dependent variables (such as range and duration) the
>   abilities might have. The creature’s caster level never affects which
>   spell-like abilities the creature has; sometimes the given caster
>   level is lower than the level a spellcasting character would need to
>   cast the spell of the same name. If no caster level is specified, the
>   caster level is equal to the creature’s Hit Dice. The saving throw (if
>   any) against a spell-like ability is:
>
> 10 + the level of the spell the ability resembles or duplicates + the
>   creature’s Cha modifier.
>
> Some spell-like abilities duplicate spells that work differently when
>   cast by characters of different classes. A monster’s spell-like
>   abilities are presumed to be the sorcerer/wizard versions. If the
>   spell in question is not a sorcerer/wizard spell, then default to
>   cleric, druid, bard, paladin, and ranger, in that order.
>
> Some creatures are actually sorcerers of a sort. They cast arcane
>   spells as sorcerers do, using components when required. In fact, an
>   individual creature could have some spell-like abilities and also cast
>   other spells as a sorcerer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s the same mechanics for starting a standard bardic performance. From the SRD:

> Once per day per bard level, a bard can use his song or poetics to
>   produce magical effects on those around him (usually including
>   himself, if desired). While these abilities fall under the category of
>   bardic music and the descriptions discuss singing or playing
>   instruments, they can all be activated by reciting poetry, chanting,
>   singing lyrical songs, singing melodies, whistling, playing an
>   instrument, or playing an instrument in combination with some spoken
>   performance. Each ability requires both a minimum bard level and a
>   minimum number of ranks in the Perform skill to qualify; if a bard
>   does not have the required number of ranks in at least one Perform
>   skill, he does not gain the bardic music ability until he acquires the
>   needed ranks.
>
> **Starting a bardic music effect is a standard action.** Some bardic
>   music abilities require concentration, which means the bard must take
>   a standard action each round to maintain the ability. Even while using
>   bardic music that doesn’t require concentration, a bard cannot cast
>   spells, activate magic items by spell completion (such as scrolls),
>   spell trigger (such as wands), or command word. Just as for casting a
>   spell with a verbal component, a deaf bard has a 20% chance to fail
>   when attempting to use bardic music. If he fails, the attempt still
>   counts against his daily limit.